# Materials dont appear the same on differnt objects

Tags: materials

I've got the same material on two different objects with the 'texture space' set as the same on both objects. Yet the material appears as it should on one (bottom part), but not the other. As you can see in the image it lacks detail on one part. This is a procedural material. Thanks!
[image: Correct application bottom]

Comment: Apply object scale? Ctrl + A -> Scale

Comment: if Allens comment doesnt help, pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Hi Guys,
It didn't work I don't think, please see attached file, https://we.tl/t-Gt23tv4SZS
Thanks!

Comment: I think I sorted it by using Smart UV.